# JMeter issue with Beanshellpreprocessor while using to set Header Information

Tags: java, jmeter

As I am trying to customize the Headers to send live time to get the right response, I am trying to use `BSH Pre-processor` to set the Header, I see the header attribute being created and values from the script as applied the logic are also working, but when I run it, it doesn't return the values.

In console I also see the issue in console as

```
2016/08/23 07:10:05 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Header;  long fromtime = 14719164 . . . '' Token Parsing Error: Lexical error at line 14, column 3.  Encountered: "a" (97), after : "\'s" 
2016/08/23 07:10:05 WARN  - jmeter.modifiers.BeanShellPreProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval    Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Header;  long fromtime = 14719164 . . . '' Token Parsing Error: Lexical error at line 14, column 3.  Encountered: "a" (97), after : "\'s" 
2016/08/23 07:10:06 INFO  - jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: To Time is ******1471916406355 
2016/08/23 07:10:06 INFO  - jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: fromtime value is ******1471916406355
```

I compared the request with working ones and it looks exactly equal, but do not work.

Please suggest if I am doing something wrong.

The `BSHPreprocessor` can be found as below:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Header;

long fromtime = ${__javaScript(Math.round(new Date().getTime()))}l;
long ttt = 3599000l;
long totime = fromtime + ttt; 

String strLong = Long.toString(fromtime);
log.info("To Time is ******" + strLong);
log.info("fromtime value is ******" + fromtime);

sampler.getHeaderManager().add(new Header("to-time"," " +totime));
sampler.getHeaderManager().add(new Header("from-time"," " +strLong));
```

Please help me at the earliest possible

Answer (score 0):

According to your message, something is wrong at line 14, column 3

> Lexical error at line 14, column 3.  Encountered: "a" (97), after : "\'s"

Your script contains 12 lines only so I have no idea what is failing there. I tried it out and it works as expected.

---

In regards to "earliest possible" workaround, given we are not telepathic enough to guess what is wrong with the missing line in your script, here is an alternative solution. Personally I try to avoid scripting and try to use JMeter built-in components where possible as these scripting engines cause some overhead.

Particularly in your case you can do what you need with the help of [JMeter Functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) only, [__longSum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__longSum) function in particular.

In your HTTP Header Manager define the following headers:

1. `from-time` with the value of

   ```
   ${__javaScript(${__javaScript(Math.round(new Date().getTime()))},fromTime)}
   ```

   2. `to-time` with the value of

      ${__longSum(${fromTime},3599000,)}

[image: Header Manager + Functions]

See [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) articles series for comprehensive information on `__longSum()` and other JMeter Functions.